# Connecting to mysql from your server

Tags: php, sql

I am trying to upload a portfolio site which uses a mysql Database, I have been just Xampp for testing it, but now I wanna upload and I keep getting can't connect to DB when I upload to my site, let me know what I need to put instead of local to connect to schellshockdesign.com
 thanks

```
<?php
//connect to database
$db = mysql_connect( 'localhost', 'blog_ss_user', 'secret' );
//choose the right DB
mysql_select_db( 'schells_portfolio', $db ) or die( 'could not connect to DB' );
```

Comment: You need to give your remote database (on schellshockdesign.com) permissions to allow you remote connections. Check out http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-do-i-enable-remote-access-to-mysql-database-server.html , it could help you.

Comment: Do you want to migrate your local works to your server with domain name you mentioned?

Answer (score 0):

http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-do-i-enable-remote-access-to-mysql-database-server.html

You have to enabled remote access so that you can connect remotely.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do/ check two things:

1. Check that you have **permissions** to access the MySQL server **remotely**.
2. Type the **correct domain name** that the MySQL server is **located at**.

Answer (score 0):

Start reading about json_encode. Crete a secret php file on your live server. Pass the data from local to live like http://www.domain.com/secretfile.php?data=$json; Now, catch with $_GET['data'], decode the json with json_decode($_GET['data']); and establish the Db connectiuon and insert your data.

Answer (score -1):

Insert your website address into the connection process
$db = mysql_connect( 'schellshockdesign.com', 'blog_ss_user', 'secret' );

Comment: That's not enough, I'm afraid.

Comment: @SchellShockDesigns Follow the guide in NeoAdonis' comment, you have to explicitly grant access to a remote user from the host/IP address you are remote connecting from.